# Dynamically Add Code to IFrame without Reloading HTML or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Weave: http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#5dbb5ce4a85bcaf4c5805e337c829e73

I have three textareas:

1 for HTML
1 for CSS
and 1 for JavaScript code

Whenever code is added in these textareas (I'm using keyup for the same of this post) I call a function called `runEditor` which adds the code into the iframe.

What I'm trying to figure out is how can I call the same function when CSS is added without adding the HTML or the JavaScript again?

```js
var htmlEditor = document.querySelector(".html")
var cssEditor  = document.querySelector(".css")
var jsEditor   = document.querySelector(".js")

function runEditor() {
  var previewFrame = document.querySelector(".preview")
  var preview =  previewFrame.contentDocument ||  previewFrame.contentWindow.document

  preview.open()
  preview.write("<style>"+ cssEditor.value +"</style>" + htmlEditor.value + "<scr"+"ipt>"+ jsEditor.value +"</scr"+"ipt>")
  preview.close()
}
runEditor()

htmlEditor.onkeyup = function() {
  runEditor()
}
cssEditor.onkeyup = function() {
  runEditor()
}
jsEditor.onkeyup = function() {
  runEditor()
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
}

.preview {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="html">
<button>
  Hello world
</button>

<div class="output"></div>
</textarea>
<textarea class="css">body {
  background: #52b165;
}</textarea>
<textarea class="js">
var output  = document.querySelector(".output")
var btn     = document.querySelector("button")
var counter = 0

function addElm() {
  var node = document.createElement("div")
  var txt = document.createTextNode("hi " + counter++)
  node.appendChild(txt)
  output.appendChild(node)
}

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  addElm()
})
</textarea>
<iframe class="preview" sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set up the iframe, you have access to both `window` and `document` objects inside the iframe. You have access to methods like `document.getElementById` and friends.

To reload the CSS, suggesting you create a `<style>` element in the iframe. When CSS changes, wipe out the contents of that element and put in the new CSS. HTML can do the same, wiping out the HTML of `<body>` and replacing it with the new HTML. `innerHTML` will be your friend. JS will be a bit tricky. You will need to recreate the iframe from the beginning to start fresh.

Comment: I figured it'd be something like that I just couldn't figure out how to do it within preview.write(). [Which I later realized](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#f6d9a54288f17fb68a8b234ec364dc41) you do it after write has been called lol (Haven't learned of a non jquery alternative to `$(".preview").contents().find("#stylethis").html(cssEditor.value)`)